# How to make images clickable to display a subset Dataframe ? (R Shiny )

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, onclick, shinyjs

Hello I am new to RShiny, and I'm trying to build an application for a project.

I have 5 images in my UserInterface I would like to make them clickable : When you click on image, it displays a subset of the dataframe in the mainPanel.

My Dataframe contains a column called "Mood",and there are 5 moods ("Party and Dance", "Rap","Happy vibes" , "Sunday Chillout" and "Roadtrip music"). Each image should display rows of one of the moods.

This is the code I have used for now :

**UI.R**

```
shinyUI(

  fluidPage(  useShinyjs(), 

             headerPanel(
               h1(img(src="logo.png",height  = 70, width = 70),"Quelle est votre humeur du moment ?",
                  style = "font-weight: 500; color: #FFFFFF;")),

   dashboardSidebar(
     fluidRow(
       column(width=11.9, align="center",
              selectInput("Mood", label= "Choose your Mood : ", 
                             choices = test$Mood),
                 img(id="my_img1",src="party.jfif",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
                 img(id="my_img2",src="cluster 2.jpg",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
                 img(id="my_img3",src="roadtrip.jpg",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
                 img(id="my_img4",src="rap.jfif",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
                 img(id="my_img5",src="sunday.jpg",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;")),

 column(11.2, align="center",
      mainPanel(br(),br(),DT::dataTableOutput("dynamic"), width = "100%"))
 ))))
```

**Server.R**

For now I have just managed to link the Select box to the subset dataframe, but I would like to get rid of it and only use the images instead.

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$dynamic<- DT::renderDataTable({

  data <- DT::datatable(test[test$Mood ==input$Mood, c("Song","Artist","Mood","Listen to song"), drop = FALSE], escape = FALSE)
  data   

  })
})
```

I have tried lots of combinations but all of them failed, because I don't have basic skills of how Shinyjs works.

My last attempt: (I thought about doing this manually for each image but it's not working of course)

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
 onclick("my_img1",     { print(datatable(test[test$Mood =="Party and dance", c("Song","Artist","Mood","Listen to song"), drop = FALSE], escape = FALSE))})

})
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated !! Thank you !

This is what my interface looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I used Shiny so I may be a bit rusty. But here is a possible approach to tackling your issue: You could use a `reactiveValue` to keep track of which mood is selected, and update that variable whenever one of the images is clicked. Then use that `reactiveValue` in subsetting your `dataframe`, as shown below. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

df = data.frame(mood = c('mood1','mood1','mood1','mood2','mood2','mood2'), 
                example = c('dog',' cat','bunny','elephant','t-rex','not dog'))

ui <- shinyUI(

  fluidPage(  
    useShinyjs(), 
    img(id="my_img1",src="img1.png",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
    img(id="my_img2",src="img1.png",width="19.5%",style="cursor:pointer;"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("dynamic")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){


  selected_mood <- reactiveVal()
  shinyjs::onclick("my_img1",  selected_mood('mood1'))
  shinyjs::onclick("my_img2",  selected_mood('mood2'))
  output$dynamic<- DT::renderDataTable({  
    req(selected_mood())
    df[df$mood == selected_mood(),]
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```